# Can i standardize a whole dataframe with the same mean instead of a new mean for every column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with temperature Data of different rooms. So the Index is datetimes and the columns are the room numbers. I want to standardize the whole dataframe with only one mean over all the data. I tried it with StandardScaler from sklearn, but it will standardize all columns on their own and not all the data together. Is there a way to tell the StandardScaler, that the columns aren't different features?

The only workaround i could think of was creating a new dataframe with a multiindex for rooms and datetimes and having all the data in one column, but that would be more confusing for me to work with.

Edit: I don't think the suggested thread answers my question, because i don't want to group my data or scale anything independently. It's kinda the opposite, because i want to scale everything together without the data being split into columns or groups.

Comment: I believe `StandardScaler` will use the shape of the DataFrame (or array) to determine which columns are considered different features. So you could flatten the entire DataFrame, pass it to StandardScaler, and then reshape it. Also I agree that your question was perhaps a bit hastily closed so I've voted to reopen

Comment: Thank you @DerekO for your Answer. I went with reshaping the Dataframe and it works, but if there is another option, i'll still be happy about an answer.